# CloudSQL 2Gen External Master Can not Create Users in Replica

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

Only the default root user and mysql.sys user exist in the replica, but I can not create a user for the application.
I tried the web console, terraform, gcloud command, mysql create user command, but none can be created.

However, the document states that the replica creates a user.

https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/replication/replication-from-external?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

The documentation is not wrong, what happens is that there is an anomaly in the service, which [is being worked on](https://issuetracker.google.com/129571002) and will be resolved probably very soon.

Comment: It was already reported as a bug. Thank you very much.
I would like to wait for this bug to be fixed.

Comment: You're welcome. Please consider accepting my answer.